# Routh's algorithm and root analysis give contradictory results

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

I am designing a control system :

[image]

with open loop gain equal to : $\frac{K}{s(s^{2}+4s+3)}$

The closed loop gain is obviously :$\frac{K}{s(s^{2}+4s+3)+K}$

I tried finding the critical frequency but found something else interesting while trying to find the critical frequency.

I applied Ruth's algorithm to the denominator of the closed loop gain and I get this result:

[image]

Obviously for a stable system k doesnt exist but this seemed super odd so I decided to set k = 2 and find all the roots [using a calculator](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/roots-calculator/roots%20x%5E%7B3%7D%2B4x%5E%7B2%7D%2B3x%2B2?or=input) and I found that the root is in the left half plane of the Re,Im plane so the system SHOULD be stable.So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup for the Routh-Hurwitz stability criterion isn't correct. Your setup should look like:

| var | c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $s^3$ | $1$ | $3$ |
| $s^2$ | $4$ | $K$ |
| $s^1$ | $ \frac{12-K}{4} $ | $0$ |
| $s^0$ | $K$ | $0$ |

So your system is stable when $0 \leq K \leq 12$.